# Neo4j-enterprise does not allow deletions

Tags: neo4j

I have been having this error for a while:
The environment I am using is:

- Neo4j-enterprise 4.1.0 (AWS Ami ami-02a68ff704cf9a737)

I am trying to do a DETACH DELETE for cleaning up some nodes and I keep getting this error:

```
Neo4jError: Writing in reading access mode not allowed. Attempted to write to internal graph 0 (neo4j)
```

I have tried several things:

1. set flag dbms.read_only=false
2. create new users with permissions.
3. Signup for the startup program of neo4j with the same email I am using in AWS.

At this point, I am quite lost. I have to check many resources but I do not find the reason of this error.

Do you have any clue about this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. It was nothing related to the Neo4j setup or with the configuration.

The problem is produced by an ORM I am using in JavaScript, [Neode](https://github.com/adam-cowley/neode). I was using the function query, and it seems for some reason I had to use writeCypher after version 4.1.0 of Neo4j.